# R言語をミドルウェアとして使っている例を教えてください。

Tags: r

R言語に関することでの質問です。

統計分析向けプログラム言語であるR言語ですが、
プログラム言語である以上、他のシステムやソフトウェアにも組み込めるのだと思っています。

そこで質問なんですが、R言語をミドルウェアとして使っている例やメリットとデメリットを教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R言語はRという統計解析システムのためのものであって、汎用のプログラミング言語ではありません。
ミドルウェアとして機能するとは思えません。

「プログラム言語である以上、他のシステムやソフトウェアにも組み込める」というのは誤解です。

Comment: なるほど、R言語はRという統計解析システムのためのものなんですね。了解しました。

Answer (score 1):

Shiny、Plumber.io、googledrive など、Rをより汎用的なバックエンドとして稼働させる仕組みは相当に盛り上がっていますよ。

データをあっちこっち移動させると一々文字化けだなんだの問題が起こりますので、
いっそRで全部組んじゃえと個人的には思うケースが増えています。

実際社内システムに関しては相当量Rで書いています。

（え、保守できなくなる？ なんぼでも若い子育てたりますがな...）